# Percentage change with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple data frame as follows:

```
>>> df
   median quarter status
0     240  2014-1     BV
1     300  2014-2     BV
2     240  2014-3     BV
3     450  2014-4     BV 
4     300  2014-1   CORR
5     240  2014-2   CORR
6     300  2014-3   CORR
7     420  2014-4   CORR
```

Now,I want to filter values only for the first 2 quarters in a year.So i do this :

```
>>> df[df['quarter'].isin(['2014-1','2014-2'])]
    median quarter status
0     240  2014-1     BV
1     300  2014-2     BV
4     300  2014-1   CORR
5     240  2014-2   CORR
```

Now I want to find the percentage change between the median values of the 2 quarters so I do this :

```
>>> df['median'].pct_change()
0     NaN
1    0.25
2    0.00
3   -0.20
Name: median, dtype: float64
```

However,what I actually need is just the percentage change between the 2 quarters along with the status like this:

```
>>> df
    pc_change status
0   25        BV
1   -20       CORR
```

How do i do that ?

Comment: read up on pandas' `groupby` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) might suit your needs. In your test data it won't matter, but you will also want to insure the status's are sorted

```
df.sort( 'status', inplace=True)
df['change'] = df['median'].pct_change()
#   median quarter status  change
#0     240  2014-1     BV     NaN
#1     300  2014-2     BV    0.25
#2     300  2014-1   CORR    0.00
#3     240  2014-2   CORR   -0.20

df.query( 'quarter=="2014-2"')
#   median quarter status  change
#1     300  2014-2     BV    0.25
#3     240  2014-2   CORR   -0.20
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to do a pivot table. An easy way to do this is by setting your index to quarter and status and then unstacking status:

```
df = df[df['quarter'].isin(['2014-1','2014-2'])]
df_qtr = df.set_index(['quarter', 'status']).unstack('status')
>>> df_qtr
         median      
status       BV  CORR
quarter              
2014-1      240   300
2014-2      300   240
```

No you can easily get the percent change:

```
>>> df_qtr.pct_change()
         median      
status       BV  CORR
quarter              
2014-1      NaN   NaN
2014-2     0.25  -0.2
```